# Confirmation on tab selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, browser, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a page with bootstrap tabs to dispaly data. In that page while the user leave the page a confirmation is been shown using the following script

[image]

```
$(window).bind('beforeunload', function() { 
      return settings.unsavedAlertMessage;  //which is transalated in the application
});
```

But now I need to implement the same confirmation box on the tab switch. Which we implement using the code snippet

```
$(document).on('hide.bs.tab', '#paneltab', function (e) {
    if(window.confirm('Are you sure')){
        e.preventDefault();
    }
})
```

[image]

But the confirmation box is not same as the first one. I need to get the same confirmation box, as the browser will handle tranlations of the texts.
How can I get the same confirmation box

Comment: `//which is transalated in the application`. How in the world could we know what the first confirmation box is? You are providing no information on the first confirmation other than stating there is one.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek I have attached the confirmation box. It is default confirmation box that is displayed when 'beforeunload' is attached.

Comment: How is your second confirmation box looks like. Post it also.

Comment: @Dotnetpickles I have attached the new image too.